# ¿Como puedo mostrar un JSON de forma interactiva?

Tags: angular, json, typescript

tengo un JSON que se genera por medio de la información de una DB de Mongo, y la tengo que mostrar en pantalla, y buscando ejemplos e ideas vi uno que me gustó en una página gubernamental
[image: Ejemplo del JSON]

Así se ve su JSON y se puede esconder o mostrar más dependiendo de a que instancias se le de click, la pagina es: https://www.plataformadigitalnacional.org/contrataciones
Estuve revisando y es con una función que oculta el contenido y lo muestra dependiendo de a que span se le de click, mi duda es ¿Hay alguna librería o algo semejante que haga algo parecido o se debe programar desde 0?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: En primer lugar, una respuesta JSON no debiera ser más que eso. Si consideras empezar a formatear tu JSON entonces podrías estar ensuciando la respuesta con elementos innecesarios.
Si quieres ver el JSON formateado existen diferentes paginas web que lo formatearán por ti, hay extensiones para el navegador o otras herramientas para consumir end points que lo harán por ti (como postman).
Si necesitas mostrar un JSON bonito, entonces replantea si realmente necesitas mostrarlo como JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si lo que buscas es una librería como la de Primeng.

Te adjunto la URL:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/setup

Saludos